# what is ami did not recognise the action type 'uiasendkeys'

Tags: amazon-ami, blueprism, uia

when I'm trying to import a `bprelease` file... then `blueprism` is throwing an error saying:

```
>  "An error occurred while attempting to import the release:  AMI did
> not recognise the action type 'UIASendKeys'"...
```

Can anyone please resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

This exception says that you are trying to import an object, that has an element spied using the UI Automation mode, and on which the `Send Keys` action is invoked.

My best guess is that you have an earlier version of Blue Prism that did not have the UI Automation mode available (it was introduced in BP6). What version do you have?

You can also open the .bprelease file, find where the UISendKeys is used and check if it looks OK. You could probably even remove the entire stage from the file and try to import it without it.

This is how it should look. Check whether the action arguments structure looks the same.

```
<stage stageid="some_stage_id" name="Send Keys Stage" type="Navigate">
    <subsheetid>some_sheet_id</subsheetid>
    <loginhibit />
    <narrative>
    </narrative>
    <displayx>15</displayx>
    <displayy>-30</displayy>
    <displaywidth>120</displaywidth>
    <displayheight>60</displayheight>
    <font family="Segoe UI" size="10" style="Regular" color="000000" />
    <onsuccess>next_stage_id</onsuccess>
    <step>
      <element id="action_on_element_id" />
      <action>
        <id>UIASendKeys</id>
        <arguments>
          <argument>
            <id>newtext</id>
            <value>"Testing keys"</value>
          </argument>
          <argument>
            <id>interval</id>
            <value>
            </value>
          </argument>
        </arguments>
      </action>
    </step>
  </stage>
```

Comment: Updated my answer, please check again.